# Set up an expiration date for a local file - Windows/Linux

Tags: linux, windows, file, date

I want to set up an expiration date for a file I send to my client. I.e. I send a pdf or doc file and I'd like that my client won't be able to open it after 7 days from getting it. Is it possibile to achieve in Windows or Linux? Without any additional programs?

Comment: You need to apply some kind of DRM to the PDF. I think that is possible. Some eBooks are distributed that way.

Comment: If your client is as smart as you, he'll be able to circumvent your tricks....

Answer (score 1):

It can't be done without any additional programs. Adobe offers various [DRM solutions](http://www.adobe.com/manufacturing/resources/drm/) for PDFs, I think an expiration date is one of them. It might be very expensive. I'm assuming you want to send a sample of your work to the client, but want to make sure they can't use it without paying for it. Shouldn't copy right law be able to protect you in this case?

Comment: It should be but it's not :)

Comment: It's a pity you can't trust your customers

Answer (score 1):

You can set expiry date on PDFs by the help of JavaScript.
See these links on how to do it 
http://forums.adobe.com/thread/286036

http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Adding-Expiry-Date-PDFs-159987.S.210515733

http://answers.acrobatusers.com/Can-I-set-expiration-date-PDF-Adobe-Acrobat-X-Pro-q37922.aspx

http://www.root-path.net/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=78:expiration-date-for-pdf-documents&catid=43:scripts&Itemid=82